# How to hide IOS App Temporarily in App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

Is it possible to temporarily hide my iOS app from App Store for a while. In pricing and availability do i uncheck all the countries availability or i have to select the Remove from Sale. And what will happen if i uncheck all the countries availability only and click on save button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove from sale will do the job :)

Comment: For an example after few days if i decide to show the app then what is the procedure or do i have to start it once again like first time ?